# Phaser, Image Replaced By Green Square, No Errors, JS

Tags: javascript, image, game-development, phaser-framework, parcel

I followed many Phaser tutorials online with precision, and made sure the path to the image is adequate, yet I find myself stuck with a green square with a dash across it in place for my image
[green square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSAcK.png).

I have suspicions that perhaps it's the way I have my testing server set up, I am using parcel for this. I've tried many implementations of loading images using Phaser's preLoad() function, but even the simplest one `this.load.image('testing','../../assets/user/body/moveRightAtlas.png');` (in preLoad) and `var testing=this.add.sprite(400,400,'testing');` (in create) still prints the square. For the path, I've tried absolute path and still does not work. Here is how my directories are set up. [directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbKvv.png) . My question is, what am I doing incorrect? I'm an absolute noob in Phaser, so any help is deeply appreciated, thanks.

(EDIT: for the directories screenshot I accidently said moveRight0, I meant moveRightAtlas.png)

After reading more, it seems that the image exists but the web server I am using to test the game can't seem to load it. So the issue is likely on the webserver. I am using parcel.

Comment: Can you share some more code? this would make it simpler to find the problem

Comment: thank you for your time man, All that I have is an empty scene with the code above that I mentioned. Then it is started in the main file. I can assure you everything in main and scene is correctly written. I edited the question above to mention that it is likely a problem with the web server I set up not being able to load the resources, I am clueless after this lol.

Answer (score 1):

The path should be relative to the HTML file, so in your case:

```
this.load.image('testing','assets/user/body/moveRightAtlas.png');
```

Comment: thanks, but I've tried this.

Comment: @IAmNoob If you load the image in `preload` and add the image in `create` it should work. Is the image valid?

Comment: it is indeed valid

Answer (score 0):

You should probably move the assets directory inside your `src` and then go from there.

[Here's how](https://github.com/samme/phaser-parcel/blob/master/src/BootScene.js) this samme's repository for [a working parcel setup](https://github.com/samme/phaser-parcel) is doing the imports :

```
[...]
    import images from './assets/*.png';
[...]
    this.load.image('space', images.space);
[...]
```

In your case it'd probably be something like:

```
[...]
     import moveRightAtlas from './assets/user/body/moveRightAtlas.png'; 
[...]
     this.load.image('testing', moveRightAtlas);
[...]
```

Check also its README for a plugin to copy the assets.